# horizontal line with two colors

Tags: html, line

I am trying the simulate the same effect on the picture for an html page. Is it possible to accomplish this without using an image or JS? I know it can be done horizontally by adding border color top and bottom but I couldn't find a way to do it horizantally.

[image]

Comment: It's been awhile since I've done html, but I would probably use frames. Dunno if people still do that anymore though...

Comment: Can you give us some code you are using? I'm sure it can be accomplished with css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a grey `border-bottom` to your element and overlap it partially with a red `::after` pseudo-element:

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
}
h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EC1C24;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Haberler</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.line {
    background:gray;
    position:relative;
    height:2px;
}
.line:before {
    content:'';
    background:red;
    width:30%;
    height:2px;
    position:absolute;    
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
hr {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 0;
}

hr:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a few inline block elements with borders, but I'm not sure if it's worth it (instead of using an image):

```css
div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: red 2px solid;
  border-top: blue 2px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  }

#a {
  width: 240px;
  border-top: green 2px solid;
  border-bottom: gray 2px solid
    }
```

```html
<div></div><div id="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="height:2px;">
        <td style="width:10%;background-color:#003b67;"></td>
        <td style="width:90%;background-color: #4cff00;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension to @Thilina Dharmasena original post.

I used his implementation to create a progress bar with styled-components

```js
<ProgressBar scroll='90%' />

const ProgressBar = styled.div`
  background: #191923;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    background: #ffc107;
    width: ${({ scroll }) => scroll};
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
  }
`;
```